# can my server trust the access token from auth0?

Tags: .net, auth0

I'm using this workflow: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow

In step 5, the app make a request with an accesstoken which is generated by auth0

This is the guide to validate the access token in the server: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/interactive

According to the guide, I see they only validate the issuer and audience, what if someone know the issuer and audience and create a fake access token with that information? will my server be tricked?

Is there a way to validate the access token in my server securely?

Comment: "what if someone know the issuer and audience and create a fake access token with that information?" well, unless they have access to your client id & client secret, how would they do that?

Comment: they can do that open the network tab in the browser, find the /token route and the the access token, then they can decode it using jwt.io

Comment: Noooo. The client id and secret should never be exposed in your front-end. You should call auth0's `/authorize` endpoint only from a back-end!

Comment: The token contains a hash of the contents. If you change anything in it, the hash would be invalid and the token would be rejected. Only the actual issuer can properly hash its tokens.

Comment: you get me wrong, when you authenticate, the auth0 will return you an access token and id token, user can easily see them by opening the network tab, so that they can easily see the issuer and audience of the token. I'm not talking about client id and secret

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi well, not about changing the info, I'm talking about creating a new access token with the same information, according to the guide, they only validate the isusser and audience (they don't validate the signing key, that's the problem)

Comment: When a JWT is created, a hash is made of the content of the JWT, including a timestamp. For this hash the server uses a private key. If you want to validate the JWT, thus check the hash,  you need the public key of the JWT server (Auth0). You can download this from the .well-know url.

Comment: @L01NL, exactly what I want, public key. thanks so much

Comment: @vupham, great! I'll extend my comment a bit a change it to the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access token, generated by Auth0, is in the format of a Json Web Token (JWT).
In its compact form, JSON Web Tokens consist of three parts separated by dots (.), which are:

- Header
- Payload
- Signature

When a JWT is created, a signature is made of the content of the JWT, including a timestamp which is in the payload. For this hash the server uses a private key and an algorithm. If you want to validate the JWT, thus check the hash, you need the public key of the JWT server (Auth0). You can download this from the .well-know url.

https://{yourDomain}/.well-known/openid-configuration

With the public key, you can validate the content (payload) of the JWT and verify if the signature is signed by the private key of Auth0.

You can learn more about how JWT works at https://jwt.io/introduction